# How can I use both ButtonStyle() and ElevatedButton.styleFrom() in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm new to flutter and I want to apply disabled color and full-screen width to ElevatedButton.

So for applying color, I did like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style : ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {return Colors.green;}
        else {return Colors.blue;}
      }
    ),
    ...
```

And for applying width, I did like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style : ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize : const Size.fromHeight(50)
  ),
  ...
```

But I have no idea how can I combine them. Please tell me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `minimumSize` in `ButtonStyle` too, like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size.fromHeight(50)), /// <--- add this
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
        return Colors.green;
      } else {
        return Colors.blue;
      }
    }),
  ),
  onPressed: (){},
  child: Container(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` extension

```
 ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            style:
                ElevatedButton.styleFrom(minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50))
                    .merge(ButtonStyle(    //  use merge here
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                  return Colors.green;
                } else {
                  return Colors.blue;
                }
              }),
            )),
            child: const Text("Hello"),
          ),
```

With this approach, you'll be able to use both the `minimumSize` and `backgroundColor` properties for your `ElevatedButton`.

You can also use other properties that `ElevatedButton.styleFrom()` and `ButtonStyle()` have and combine them as you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is also a very effective solution. Though I chose an answer that I received earliest as the best one, this also helped me understand. I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property is used to customize the appearance of the button. First, it uses the `ElevatedButton.styleFrom()` method to create a new `ButtonStyle` object, and sets the `minimumSize` property to `Size.fromHeight(40)`, which means that the button will have a minimum height of 40.

Then, it uses the `merge()` method to merge the newly created `ButtonStyle` object with an existing `ButtonStyle` object. This allows you to customize the style of the button without overwriting the existing styles.

It then uses the `backgroundColor` property to set the background color of the button based on its enabled/disabled state by using `MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith` method, which allows you to provide a callback that returns a different color based on the button's `MaterialState`.

This callback checks if the button is in the disabled state by checking if the MaterialState.disabled is present in the states set, if it is present it returns the color grey else it returns the color blue.

Finally, it sets the child property to a Text widget with the text "Action Title", which is displayed on the button.

The button will be rendered with a disabled state, and its background color will be grey and its minimum height will be 40, and it will display the text "Action Title"

```dart
  ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
//action
},     
            style:
                ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(40))
                    .merge(ButtonStyle(    //  use merge here
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                  (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                  return Colors.grey;
                } else {
                  return Colors.blue;
                }
              }),
            )),
            child: const Text("Action Title"),
          ),
```

You can pass null to the `onPressed` property to see the button disable state.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: null,
    // other properties
    )
```